# Android - incrementing global variables

Tags: android, global

I'm trying to Make an app with proximity gestures. I have set up a proximity sensor in the main activity:

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    SensorManager sm;
    Sensor proxSensor;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list();
        Global g = Global.getInstance();
        g.setData(0);
        int data=g.getData();

    }
    public void list() {
        sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        proxSensor=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

        sm.registerListener(this, proxSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub





    }
```

Also, I have set up a global variable in a singleton class, and referenced it in the main activity:

```
public class Global {
    private static Global instance;
    private int data;

    private Global() {}

    public void setData(int d){
        this.data=d;
    }
    public int getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public static synchronized Global getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance=new Global();
        }
        return instance;
    }



}
```

I am trying to count sensor updates with the global variable.
Could anyone please tell me how to:

1. Add 1 to the value of the global variable everytime the sensor is triggored
2. Once the global variable has reached a certain value, to trigger an activity.

Code would be greatly appreciated, as I am completley clueless on this subject.

Thank you!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Is the code you're currently using written by you? (If so, these should be trivial modifications.)

Comment: I have tried using an if else statement, but it gave me errors

Comment: In the future, show what you've tried (along with any errors), otherwise it just looks like you're asking people to do the work for you.

Comment: Ok sorry. I'll do that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Eric with his comment. See the example bellow, you can do it some other way also based on your requirement.

```
public void updateData(Context context){
    this.data++;
    if (this.data==LIMIT){
        Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentClass.this, ClassToStart.class);
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```